# SQL DATEDIFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014

I am working on SQL server using SSMS 2014

```
select DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())
```

gives output as 1409 (run on 16-06-2017)

I am confused because DATEDIFF syntax's 2nd and 3rd parameter should be a valid date but here how and why is this query executing and giving result when 2nd parameter is 0.

I checked ISDATE(0) and ISDATE('0') which  gives syntax error , so if 0 is not a valid date then why DATEDIFF is accepting it and giving result.

Comment: `0` translates to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` in `Sql Server`. So `month` difference between `1900-01-01` and `2017-06-16` is `1409`

Comment: but why ? what is the significance of 1900-01-01 ?

Comment: `ISDATE` isn't lying, technically: `0` isn't a valid `DATETIME` expression, it's an `INT`. However, an `INT` can be implicitly converted to a `DATETIME`.

Comment: First date of `Sql Server`

Comment: and if that is the case where it translates 0 then why  ISDATE function fails?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) and [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation specifies:

> startdate
>
> Is an expression that can be resolved to a time, date, smalldatetime,
>   datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset value.

Although a subtle distinction, "can be resolved" is not the same as "is the type of".

So, an *integer* is interpreted as the number of days since '1899-12-31'.  However, strings are not interpreted as days, even when they look like a number.

`ISDATE()` takes a *string* argument, so it is converting `0` to `'0'`.  And `'0'` is not a date format.  In fact, `datediff()` will fail with the second argument passed as `'0'` rather than `0`.

And (although pretty much never used), any integer will work as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

1409 is the number of months since January 1900.

01-01-1900 is the default date for SQL Server.

if you execute :

```
select DATEADD(mm,-1409, GETDATE())
```

You will find : `1900-01-16 14:25:09.760`